# Routing in Laravel module

Tags: laravel-5

I created a module in Laravel 5 i.e inside the same level as the app folder as part of making an HMVC structure in Laravel. I have two modules in the module folder, one being a project folder and another a form folder. Now I got the controller, model and view inside these folders.

[Click here to view folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiMVv.png)

Now when i try to access my controller like

```
Route::controller('project/dashboard', 'ProjectController@index');
```

I get error

```
ReflectionException in ControllerInspector.php line 35:
Class ProjectController does not exist
```

I would like to know about routing a controller in modular structure in Laravel.

Answer (score 2):

When use `Route::controller` use this `Route::controller('project/dashboard','ProjectController');`

And inside your controller define methods like

```
public function getIndex(){
    // write your code here
}

public function postIndex(){
    // write your code here
}
public function getCreate(){
    // write your code here
}

public function postStore(){
    // write your code here
}
```

Comment: In the above code to which method will it be directed in the 'ProjectController'?

Comment: When you use `getIndex()` it will redirected as `get` method, if you use `postIndex()` it will be post method.

Answer (score 0):

You are having that problem because that **modules** directory is not visible to Laravel's psr module. Based on laravel version what you can do is put your **modules** directory into `psr` in composer after `"App\\": "app/",`

Eg:

`"psr-4": {
   "App\\": "app/",
   "Modules\\": "modules/"
}`

in *app.php* which resides in either `app/config/app.php` or in `config/app.php` in laravel 5.

And then execute the composer command `composer dump-autoload -o`.
Here you go now your modules will work as you wished.

If still having trouble you can try this package which does the same thing you are trying to. https://github.com/yubarajshrestha/laravel-module