# How to link assets which are inside of module in Laravel?

Tags: php, css, laravel, module, assets

I have problem to provide assets such as images, css, javascript when using module. Each module has each set of assets such as javascript, css, images inside of resources folder of that particular module and that i just compiled to inside of public folder of module. I have problem to provide to link to that assets.

I provide the link like this way

```html
<link href="{{ asset('modules/robust/core/public/admin/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

It shows this kind of result 
[image]

I think i should define the custom path for the module assets But i do not know how to do that. Please help me.

Folder structure is like this.

[image]

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by **I have problem to provide assets such as images, css, javascript when using module.** What module are you talking about?

Comment: i am talking about custom module using laravel for e.g. blog, product, page modules etc. Each module has it's own assets path.

Comment: Can you try using `{{ url('modules/robust/core/public/admin/css/app.css') }}` method once?

Comment: @prateekkathal folder structure is like this which i include above.

Comment: yes i tried but not working,  not found exception in console.

Comment: did u cheked inspect element ? path is correct ?

Comment: @MadhuSudhanSubedi Yes, a custom path will be required to access files for that. May I know why you are trying to use a separate folder and not the public folder for this?

Comment: yes i checked path is http://localhost:8000/modules/robust/core/public/admin/css/app.css

I think i should define public path for the core module first , i do not know i can i do that would you like to help me ?

Comment: @prateekkathal  I do not know what is the best way to make modular application in laravel. if i put separate assets inside resources/assets folder of each module and compile them to the default public folder of laravel it will work for all modules i just afraid of that is the best way ? Please suggest me ! sorry for poor english.

Comment: @MadhuSudhanSubedi If you want to make a modular application, I'd suppose you read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28485690/how-to-structure-a-modular-app-in-laravel-5) once. Also, I suggest you **separate out images/css/js files in public folder** and put only routes & views in the **app/Modules/blog** or **app/Modules/anything**. :)

Comment: @prateekkathal ok thanks for the suggestion, Now i do not need to override the publicPath for each module i will configure it in modular way inside of root-directory/public directory.

Comment: @MadhuSudhanSubedi Cool! Please accept my answer :)

Comment: @prateekkathal I accepted :D. my question is getting -1 vote please and make it 0 :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per our conversation in the comments, I suggest you divide your project in the following manner

- app/Modules/

  - blog/
  - core/
  - etc.../
- public/

  - blog/css
  - blog/js
  - blog/images
  - core/css
  - core/js
  - core/images
  - etc.../css
  - etc.../js
  - etc.../images

And then use commands like this in Controller

```
$this->loadViewsFrom()
```

and in View, you can use this

```
{{ asset('blog/images/myimage.jpg') }}
```

If there are are more issue, please let me know by commenting below :)

Glad I could be of help :D

Comment: Thanks for the help ! 
ok sure if any issues occur i will let you know !

Answer (score 3):

Use this command :

```
php artisan module:publish
```

and get assets files like this :

```
{{ Module::asset('blog:js/script.js') }}
```

Comment: do you set instead of "blog" your module name? this work for me. {{ Module::asset('blog:js/script.js') }}

Answer (score 2):

You can create a route path in route.php file:

```js
Route::get('/assets/{module}/{type}/{file}', [ function ($module, $type, $file) {
    $module = ucfirst($module);

    $path = app_path("Modules/$module/Resources/Blocks/$type/$file");

    if (\File::exists($path)) {
        return response()->download($path, "$file");
    }

    return response()->json([ ], 404);
}]);
```

Comment: Good one to use. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
{{ Module::asset('blog:js/script.js') }}
```

This assumes your script is located at /Modules/ModuleName/Assets/js/script.js. If it is not in a folder, just omit the js/ part in the asset call.

Comment: YOur answer is work when some one using nWidart/laravel-modules package. It's not working for caffeinated/modules package.

Comment: Oh yes nWidart/laravel-modules package only.

Comment: because i am using caffeinated/modules package and stuck here so i want to find solution.